# remove [] from a dataframe in python

Tags: python

I have a dataframe with []

I want to remove [] from the Name column

I tried this:

```
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace("['", "")
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace("']", "")
```

But it seems not working

Comment: What do you mean by it seems not working? Do you have an error? Does it give you an unexpected result? It will help us answer your problem

Comment: unterminated character set at position 0 is the error message

Comment: @BrownBear AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values! then i get this

Comment: @BrownBear is object

Comment: put here example to create similar df to make the code reproducible
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: Are you sure your column Name is a string? It can also be simply an array, where you can not use str.replace

Comment: @robinood it is object as dtype

Comment: df['Name'] = df['name'].str.replace('[', '').str.replace(']', '')

Comment: The column contains a list, not a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your column consists of lists, not strings, so you can't use string operations on it. What you *can* (and should) do is to `.join` the lists of strings into strings separated by comma.

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Test': [['foo', 'bar'], ['baz']]})
>>> df
         Test
0  [foo, bar]
1       [baz]
>>> df.dtypes
Test    object
dtype: object
>>> df['Test'] = df.Test.str.join(',')
>>> df
      Test
0  foo,bar
1      baz
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code, namely the `'` (single-quote) character. Tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data=[
    {
        "Name": "[Name1]",
        "ID": 1
    },
    {
        "Name": "[Name2]",
        "ID": 2
    },
        {
        "Name": "[Name3]",
        "ID": 3
    }
])

print(df)
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace("[", "")
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace("]", "")
print(df)
```

which returned:

```
      Name  ID
0  [Name1]   1
1  [Name2]   2
2  [Name3]   3
/home/sawik/./playground.py:81: FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version. In addition, single character regular expressions will *not* be treated as literal strings when regex=True.
  df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace("[", "")
/home/sawik/./playground.py:82: FutureWarning: The default value of regex will change from True to False in a future version. In addition, single character regular expressions will *not* be treated as literal strings when regex=True.
  df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.replace("]", "")
    Name  ID
0  Name1   1
1  Name2   2
2  Name3   3
```